# Architecture : In SQL what is the best method to query a filtered data set?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters

In SQL what is the best method to query a filtered data set?

I imagined two solutions and I would like to know what are the advantages and incovenients one and the other.

**Solution 1**

I create one unique procedure with my filter in parameters

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetByFilter] 
(
    -- Pagination
    @p_Offset                   int,
    @p_FetchNext                int,

    -- Filters
    @p_Param1                   nvarchar(255),
    @p_param2                   uniqueidentifier,
    @p_param3                   uniqueidentifier
)
```

**Solution 2**

I create a procedure by parameter

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetByParam1] 
(
    -- Pagination
    @p_Offset                   int,
    @p_FetchNext                int,

    -- Filters
    @p_Param1                   nvarchar(255)
)

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetByParam2] 
(
    -- Pagination
    @p_Offset                   int,
    @p_FetchNext                int,

    -- Filters
    @p_param2                   uniqueidentifier
)

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetByParam3] 
(
    -- Pagination
    @p_Offset                   int,
    @p_FetchNext                int,

    -- Filters
    @p_param3                   uniqueidentifier
)
```

**Solution 3**

Another way?

Comment: Erland Sommarskog's [Dynamic Search conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) is a good read, if by SQL you actually mean SQL Server (SQL is a language, implemented in various products by different vendors. There are separate tags for each product)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Solution 1 is the best one: it allows you to filter using one or more parameters: you can set a default value for your params, or pass null values when you do not want to filter by a certain parameter. Then the filter query could be written in this way:

```
SELECT
    --your output
FROM
    Table t
WHERE 
    --some conditions AND
( @p_Param1 is null OR t.column1 = @p_Param1 ) AND
( @p_Param2 is null OR t.column2 = @p_Param2 ) AND
( @p_Param3 is null OR t.column3 = @p_Param3 )
```

Solution 2 would require a lot of new procedures if you wanted to add more filter options or, for example, filter by parameters 2 and 3 at the same time.